# How to store module name in db elixir/ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a use-case where I want to store `module_name` in my DB(Postgres). I am doing this so that later on I can retrieve the `name` and call a `function` defined inside the `module`.
e.g.

```
defmodule A do
  def a() do
  end 
end
```

Suppose I have a schema "xyz"
I want to keep a field module name in it,

```
schema "xyz" do
  field(:module, Ecto.Atom)
end
```

For now, I have kept the field to be [`Ecto.Atom`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_atom/Ecto.Atom.html) type.

Is it correct, if not what's the right way to do it?

Comment: A module name is an atom so it should work. Is it not working for you?

Comment: my bad, there was a small error I have corrected it changed `:atom_field` to `Ecto.Atom`. I have problem calling the function with the `name` I retrieved from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply/3` to call a function on a module whose name you have as an atom.

Let's say you have `Enum` atom stored in `xyz` with id `123`. You can call `Enum.map([1, 2, 3], &(&1 * &1))` like this:

```
xyz = Repo.get(Xyz, 123)
apply(xyz.module, :map, [[1, 2, 3], &(&1 * &1)]) #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

Comment: will try this out.

Comment: should it work like this also?

`iex(2)> :Enum.module` because this results in `function :Enum.module/0 is undefined (module :Enum is not available)`